# Extract data from file opened by hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

I have a URL that opens an excel sheet from yahoo finance. I want to take this sheet and then format the data before moving. However the below code finishes without formatting. Possibly to do with it taking 5 seconds for the excel sheet to open. I have tried a delay timer but this doesn't work either. Any idea how to fix, some kind of time killing loop maybe? or maybe a delay and then the need to reference the current sheet somehow.

```
Sub MAIN()

Call START

Dim i As Integer

    Workbooks("book1.xlsb").Sheets("links").Select

For i = 2 To 2
    
    Cells(i, 5).Select
    Selection.HYPERLINKS(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=False

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H1").Interior
        Columns("a:a").TextToColumns , DataType:=xlDelimited, COMMA:=True
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .TintAndShade = -0.5
        Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        Range("A:A").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        Range("B:F").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
        Range("G:G").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        Range("A:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
    Sheets("LINKS").Select
    
Next
    
Workbooks("book1.xlsb").Sheets("links").Activate

'    Windows("book1.xlsb").Activate
'    Sheets("LINKS").Select
    
Call ENDING
    
End Sub
```

[yahoo finance link](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/%5EIXIC?period1=1561008115&period2=1592630515&interval=1d&events=history)

Comment: Have you tried using `Workbooks.Open(urlHere)` to open the workbook instead of Hyperlinks.Follow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @Tim Williams using workbooks.open(url).

This not only works, but is much faster and allows me to use the text to columns function at this line also.

```
Sub MAIN1()

Call START

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 2
    
    xtable = Cells(i, 5)
    xsheet = Cells(i, 4).Value
    Workbooks.Open xsheet, , , , , , , , 2

Next
    
Call ENDING
    
End Sub
```